# How can I scroll to specific element using the waypoint scrolling?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, jquery-waypoints, waypoint

The `#2` id of an element only loads after scrolling down because I can't get it using `getElementById("#2")`.

//JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#2").offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});

// waypoint code:
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
  element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
  context: document.getElementById('#16'),
  onBeforePageLoad: function() {
    $('.loading').show();
  },
  onAfterPageLoad: function($items) {
    $('.loading').hide();
  }
});
```

Example:
On page loading only showing 1,6,3,4,5

```
 1
 6
 3
 4
 5
```

after scrolling down i only getting 2,

```
 2
```

I want to directly scroll to the '2' element in the first time age load.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do or what the problem is. Can you please edit the question to give some more details.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You got it now?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getElementById([id])` function without "#".

For your case:

Change the line `document.getElementById('#16')` into `document.getElementById('16')`

More information can be found here: [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)